# Rails how to redirect if record is not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to redirect if the record is not found.
The page is not redirect and I get the error record not found.

My controller:

```
def index
@link = Link.find(params[:id])
respond_to do |format|
    if @link.blank?
    format.html { redirect_to(root_url, :notice => 'Record not found') }
    else
    format.html { render :action => "index" }
    end
end
end
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

What I've been doing is putting this at the end of the method:

```
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  redirect_to root_url, :flash => { :error => "Record not found." }
```

Even better, put it as an around_filter for your controller:

```
around_filter :catch_not_found

private

def catch_not_found
  yield
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  redirect_to root_url, :flash => { :error => "Record not found." }
end
```

Comment: What does the around_filter filter do_

Comment: It's a [Rails filter](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters) that goes around all your actions in the controller. So for example if you also had a `show` action and an `edit` action that also tried to find a record, it would also catch the exception there.

Comment: For the sake of good resources on the web, since this was tagged as answer and people will copy/paste it, can you change flash[:error] = "Record not found." and the next line redirect_to root_url to : redirect_to root_url, :error => "Record not found". Thanks!

Comment: Sure thing, although I think anything except :alert and :notice needs to be specified with a :flash hash, which I never really understood the reasoning behind.

Comment: I'd also add `and return` to the end of your redirect

Comment: It is now `around_action` instead of `around_filter`

Answer (score 8):

error is generated by Link.find - it raises exception if object was not found

you can simplify your code quite a bit:

```
def index
  @link = Link.find_by_id(params[:id])

  redirect_to(root_url, :notice => 'Record not found') unless @link

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
  end
end
```

Comment: No, `find_by_id` will just return nil if it can't find the record, unlike `find`.

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track, just capture the `RecordNotFound` exception:

```
def index
  @link = Link.find(params[:id])
  # should render index.html.erb by default
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  redirect_to(root_url, :notice => 'Record not found')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Very tricky one ... I found a simple solution for this.... This solution works for me

@link = Link.where(:id => params[:id]).first

I am using **.first** because **.where** will return an array.Yes, of-course this array has only one element. So, When there is no record with such id, it will return an empty array, assign a blank element to @link ... Now check @link is either blank or not....

Conclusion: No need to provide exception handling for a simple check
It is problem with **.find** it throws exception when no record exist ... Use **.where**  it will return an empty array

And Sorry for my Bad English

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to use find_by. find_by will find the first record matching the specified conditions. If the record is not found it will return nil, but does not raise exception, so that you can redirect to other page.

```
def index
  @link = Link.find_by(id: params[:id])

  redirect_to(root_url, :notice => 'Record not found') unless @link
end
```