# Make 301-redirects administratable by the user in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, .htaccess, redirect, rack

we are currently relaunching a bigger website from PHP (Magento with a quite exhaustive forum) into a Rails-app while keeping the forum.

During this undertaking we will migrate quite a lot of content to new URLs, which means we'll have to 301 redirect a lot of them.

Now we all know about Apache/NGINX-rewrites. I also found https://github.com/jtrupiano/rack-rewrite for RACK.

**But is there a good way to make 301-redirects administratable by our users with Rails?** (I'm basically looking for a GEM or RACK-app, where our users can log in, then see and edit the existing redirects).

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is it possible to catch these legacy URLs with a Rails route pattern? Could you provide examples of that?

Comment: Sure. e.g. `/some-old-category/some-link` to `/some-new-category/some-other-link` or even `/old-category/*` to `/new-category/*`.
But I hoped for keeping them out of my routes and have them seperately.

Comment: That's not "sure", that's "no", I can't see a pattern to catch only old URLs, without new ones.

Comment: ...well "sure" regarding your question, if I can give an example.

Comment: Fair enough. I meant to ask whether it was possible to separate new URLs from the old ones just by a pattern. It does not appear to.

Answer (score 0):

You could store all redirects in a model with attributes "from" and "to". Then, you can manage this redirects from your admin area as you want.

Then, in your ApplicationController, you can wrap your actions in a around filter as [it says here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664822/rails-how-to-redirect-if-record-is-not-found):

```
around_filter :catch_not_found

private

def catch_not_found
  yield
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  redirect = Redirect.where(from: request.original_fullpath).first
  redirect_to "#{request.base_url}#{redirect.to}" if redirect
end
```

Comment: That is a way, you are right. I hoped that I could keep this out of my controllers and just do it via the routes. 

Also: My application has no admin-area (is a separate app). Therefore I hoped for a barebones admin-backend that comes with the GEM/RACK-app.